# How should synchronised Realm actually work

Tags: react-native, realm

I'm a newbie to both react-native and realm, but not with programming, so I'm sure I'm doing something wrong.

The scenario is I have an offline-first react native app using realm.

When I run a completely local realm file, everything works fine. I can load data (from the phone contacts) and interact with it fine.

```
realm: new Realm({schema: schemas, schemaVersion: 3,})
```

Then I tried to sync it with a Realm Object Server like this:

```
        Realm.Sync.User.login(app_config.auth_uri, app_config.default_login, app_config.default_password).then(user => {
        console.log("logged into Realm Object Server")
        const config = {
            sync: {
                user: user,
                url: app_config.db_uri,
                error: err => console.log(err)
            },
            schema: schemas,
            schemaVersion: 3,
        };

        this.realm = new Realm(config);

    }).catch(error => {
        console.log('Error with sync setup to ' + app_config.auth_uri + ' with : ' + error)
    });
```

and it connects but there is no syncing.
Worse still, because it is now in an async context, everything that expected 'realm' to be set is failing - lots of 'null' exceptions.

So my question:

How should this be working. My expectation is I get a realm immediately from both calls and the syncing part should be happening in the background.
If it fails i.e. couldn't connect or loses connection, the app should still be working.

Am I wrong, does anyone have a fuller working example of this?

Will continue search but I really appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0):

If you create a local realm that you then want to become a synced realm you need to copy it:

https://realm.io/docs/cookbook/js/local-realm-to-synced/

Alternatively, if you create a synced realm using `new Realm` as above with a sync config or creating it ahead of time on the server it'll sync as you expect.

Without seeing the urls you are using it's difficult to confirm completely your issue.

Note: I have added the fullSyncronization flag as the default is partially synced.

```
function getOpenRealm (app_config) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    Realm.Sync.User.login(app_config.auth_uri, app_config.default_login, app_config.default_password).then(user => {
      const config = {
        sync: {
          user: user,
          url: app_config.db_uri,
          error: err => console.log(err),
        },
        schema: schemas,
        schemaVersion: 3,
        fullSynchronization: true,
      }
      Realm.open(config).progress((transferred, transferable) => {
        const progressPercentage = transferred / (transferable / 100)
        console.log(`progress ${transferred}/${transferable} (${Math.round(progressPercentage, 2)}%)`)
      }).then(realm => {
        resolve(realm)
      }).catch((e) => { reject(e)})
    }).catch((e) => { reject(e)})
  })
}

getOpenRealm(app_config)
  .then(realm => {
    this.realm = realm
  })
  .catch(e => {})
```

Or cleaner using async/await...

```
async function getOpenRealm (app_config) {

  let user = await Realm.Sync.User.login(app_config.auth_uri, app_config.default_login, app_config.default_password)
  const config = {
    sync: {
      user: user,
      url: app_config.db_uri,
      error: err => console.log(err),
    },
    schema: schemas,
    schemaVersion: 3,
    fullSynchronization: true,
  }
  let realm = await Realm.open(config).progress((transferred, transferable) => {
    const progressPercentage = transferred / (transferable / 100)
    console.log(`progress ${transferred}/${transferable} (${Math.round(progressPercentage, 2)}%)`)
  })

  return realm
}

try {
  this.realm = await getOpenRealm(app_config)
}
catch(e) {
  // do what you will with e
}
```